# Retaining Value of textBox, select after modifying element

Tags: javascript, html

I have an HTML table

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td>
        Players
    </td>
    <td id="positions"></td>
</table>
```

The user can press a button and it will concatenate a dropbox and textbox to td

> positions

They user CAN set the values in dropbox and textbox and then add another player to it.

However, once he adds a new element, the values in the old dropbox and textbox are getting reset. Is it possible to keep them?

The addPosition function:

```
function addPosition (){
    var toDisplay = "";

    toDisplay += "<input type='number'>";
    toDisplay += "<select><option value='back'>Back</option><option value='front'>Front</option></select>";

    document.getElementById("positions").innerHTML += toDisplay; 
}
```

Comment: Yes, because when you set the values, javascript wont remember for them. You need to store / restore the values somehow.

Comment: Instead of building the literal HTML, use [createElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.createElement) and [appendChild](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.appendChild)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should [create](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.createElement) and [append](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.appendChild) DOM elements, rather than replacing the parent's HTML:

```
function addPosition() {
    var input = document.createElement("input");
    input.type = "number";
    var select = document.createElement("select");
    select.innerHTML = "<option value='back'>Back</option><option value='front'>Front</option>";
    var positions = document.getElementById("positions");
    positions.appendChild(input);
    positions.appendChild(select);
}
```

(Also, you're missing a closing `</tr>`)

Even better, use [document fragments](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.createDocumentFragment) for improved performance:

```
function addPosition() {
    var fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();
    var input = document.createElement("input");
    input.type = "number";
    var select = document.createElement("select");
    select.innerHTML = "<option value='back'>Back</option><option value='front'>Front</option>";
    fragment.appendChild(input);
    fragment.appendChild(select);

    document.getElementById("positions").appendChild(fragment);
}
```

[jsFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/L2o9x3x7/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe using HTML5 data element (or cookies/session if that is not an option)?

Answer (score 0):

You should create an option element in DOM and add that to your list, like in:

```
var oSelect = document.getElementById("positions");
var oOption = document.createElement("option");
oOption.text = "Next option";
oSelect.add(oOption);
```